# How to include a module in a model class with alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using `Rails` and `Mongoid` at the moment.
Suppose I have the following model:

```
class User
  include Name
end
```

And a `Name` module:

```
module Name
  included do
    field :name, type: String

    #other methods here...
  end
end
```

**Problem**

Now I want `User` to have two fields: `name` and `nickname`, both by using `Name` module. How should I do this? Thank you.

**Edit**

To carify, `name` and `nickname` share some methods, but nickname also have some special methods itself.
For example, both `name` and `nickname` can do the following:

```
def greeting(name)
  p "hello #{name}!"
end
```

But, only `nickname` can do the following:

```
def friendly_greeting(name)
  p "hello #{name}! You can call me #{nickname}"
end
```

My first thought is to create 2 modules, `Name` and `Nickname` and let `Nickname` be a subclass of `Name`. But both of them are modules so I don't know if this works.

Comment: Add `field :nickname, type: String` to `Name`. What is it exactly that you don't understand?

Comment: Hello @max, the problem is that not all models need a `nickname` field.
Say `Car` class, it can include `Name` module, but `nickname` field is not suitable in this case. Also `name` and `nickname` fields share something similar, but they also have some different implementation. Please check my edited question.

Comment: You cannot import part of a module in Ruby like you can in Python for example. Instead you need to use different modules and composition.

Comment: Your question still makes very little sense unfortunatly

Comment: @max, please check the edited answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are not classes and thus cannot use classical hierarchical inheritance. However a module can include other modules - which means you  can use paralell inheritance.

```
module Name
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    field :name, type: String
  end

  def greeting(name)
    p "hello #{name}!"
  end
end

module Nickname
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  include Name

  included do
    field :nickname, type: String
  end

  # if you named this method greeting it would
  # overwrite the implementation from the Name module
  def friendly_greeting(name)
    p "hello #{name}! You can call me #{nickname}"
  end
end

class Foo 
  include Name
end

class Bar
  include Nickname
end

Foo.new.name # nil
Foo.new.nickname # NoMethodError

Foo.fields.keys # ['_id', 'name']
Bar.fields.keys # ['_id', 'name', 'nickname']

Foo.new(name: 'Max').greeting # "hello Max!"
Foo.new(name: 'Max').friendly_greeting # NoMethodError

bar = Bar.new(name: 'Richard', nickname: 'Dick')
bar.greeting # "hello Richard!"
bar.friendly_greeting # "hello Richard! You can call me Dick"
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem max! This design pattern is really useful and everything is loosely coupled.